# How to apply a command to a list of files with spaces produced by another command?

Tags: linux

Say I have a piped command like this one:

```
$ ls -t|tail -n 10
```

Now if I want to remove all the files produced by the above command, if the files have spaces, it won't work:

```
$ rm `ls -t|tail -n 10`
# assuming the first response is 'The File Name', I get:
rm: cannot remove ‘The’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘File’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘Name’: No such file or directory
```

How can I quote the file names before sending it to rm?

Comment: You want to set IFS to something else than whitespace.

Comment: @Hennes, ``IFS='\n'  rm `ls the*` `` ?

Comment: That could work. IFS is the 'Internal File Separator'. It defaults to a space.  You could set it to any character. Newline ('\n') and null (IFS=$'\0') ae the most often used options. (Often in combination with `find -print0`.  -- However the best choice depends on what you are trying to do, and your example "ls|cut -d ' ' -f 3|sort|etc..." is to vague for me to comment on that.

Comment: $ IFS='\n'  'rm ls the*' gives me:
`rm: cannot remove ‘the file\nthe file2\nthe file3’: No such file or directory`

Comment: For just deleting I would use something like this: `find /path/to/dir -name *.avi -delete {} \;`. That looks like a solution to your goal, but not one to the question asked in the OP.

Comment: Hennes I couldn't use find since one of the etc commands was a tail which sorted my files by date.

Comment: And that's [why one should never parse the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: So, what is your real problem? Finding files with a certain date? Doesn't `find . -type f -mtime +2` or similar work for you? You can then work on that with `find … -exec`, or `find … -delete` to delete the results right away.

Comment: @slhck, I've updated the question to contain my original command. Find can't do everything. Can find filter by date? For example, how would one delete the 10 newest downloaded files.

Comment: I see. That's a little more complicated. The problem is that `ls` doesn't even produce output you can work with. With GNU `find` and `sort`, that'd be something like: `find . -type f -printf '%T@:%p\n' | sort -nr | head -n 1 | cut -d: -f2- | while read -r file; do rm "$file"; done` – this won't work with newlines though.

Comment: Whereas my ls pipe took less than 10 chars :)

Comment: Yes, but it's not reliable, just like `find`. Read [How can I get the newest (or oldest) file from a directory?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099) for some ways to alleviate this, but as you can see that's a big deficiency in Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
command that outputs files with spaces | while IFS= read -r file
do
  rm "$file"
done
```

The input will be split on newlines, so files with newlines in their name won't work. Quoting names with spaces works without problems though.

Comment: Not so for backslashes. The quoting is OK as long as you use while (which you very correctly do), it will break with `for`.

Comment: @Peter, any way to the same without the loop?

Comment: @Absolute0, you can avoid the loop by quoting the command as described in my answer. It is not a good idea though, the loop is safer if dealing with weird characters.

Comment: @Absolute0 Did this really work for you? If a file contains a space, it won't even pass through `cut -d ' '` properly.

Comment: @slhck, I wasn't actually using cut--I was trying to formulate some complex command. Should have gone with my actual command.

Comment: @Absolute0 You should have, because you accepted an answer that doesn't work :) In the future, please post actual commands rather than abstract questions.